# How to Send Image , Pdf and Few Parameters together From Angular to Node.Js Server

Tags: node.js, angular, file, multipartform-data

I am using Angular Material For getting Position of Draggable Image , getting input type file(pdf) from User and Images Stored in ./assets/emojis/. I am able to send Pdf from Angular to Node using ng2-file-upload and multer.
FrontEnd

```
<input (change)="onFileSelected()" ng2FileSelect [uploader]="uploader" type="file" id="file">
<ion-button class="input-group-text upload" (click)="uploader.uploadAll()" >Upload</ion-button>
```

Backend

```
app.post('/api/upload', upload.single('pdf'), function (req, res) {
    console.log('File is available!');
    return res.send({
      success: true
    })
  });
```

Now i have image path selected by User at assets

```
imagePathToUpload:string = './assets/emojis/'+this.selectedEmoji
topPosition:number = this.topPos
leftPosition:number = this.leftPos
```

How can i send all these data together to Server , there is one way FormData but i dont understand how to use it.
Objective is Send Image , Pdf , left and top position to server. Any Advice would be Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To send a file from Angular --> Nodejs is simple

Create upload method

```
FinalformData: FormData;
uploadFile(event) {
  if (event.target.files && event.target.files.length > 0) {
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    this.FinalformData = new FormData();
    this.FinalformData.append('file', file, file.name);
  }
}

submit() {
    // call your service and send it 
    this._sendfileService.sendFile(this.FinalformData)
        .subscribe( res => {
            if (res.success) { 
                console.log('file uploaded'); 
            } else { console.log('faild uploading file'))}
        })
}
```

all done now call your angular service with your http.post method here's and ex

```
sendFile(file: FormData): Observable<any> {
     return this.http.post<any>(this.nodejsUrl, file);
}
```

to handle the file in backend look into multer https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer

Comment: Thanks karimov but This part i already mentioned in Question. Please read Question , their no event from which i can get files. All i have is file path which i want to send to server.